# Changing MySQL WHERE params

Tags: php, mysql

I have these where params, but it's not returning what is desired:

```
WHERE `Profiles`.`Departure1` >= '2012-04-01' 
OR `Profiles`.`Departure2` >= '2012-04-01' 
OR `Profiles`.`Departure3` >= '2012-04-01' 
AND `Profiles`.`Departure1` <= '2012-04-04' 
OR `Profiles`.`Departure2` <= '2012-04-04' 
OR `Profiles`.`Departure3` <= '2012-04-04'
```

There are three departure date fields and I'm trying to only return entries where the date lands between the two dates.  What I have here is returning everything.  Is there a better way to do this that might actually work?

Comment: A bit unclear. 'The date' meaning today's date? Also you mention 3 dates, but say 'between the two dates'. Which two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use proper parenthesis:

```
WHERE ((`Profiles`.`Departure1` >= '2012-04-01' 
OR `Profiles`.`Departure2` >= '2012-04-01' 
OR `Profiles`.`Departure3` >= '2012-04-01' )
AND (`Profiles`.`Departure1` <= '2012-04-04' 
OR `Profiles`.`Departure2` <= '2012-04-04' 
OR `Profiles`.`Departure3` <= '2012-04-04'))
```

Answer (score 4):

Use mySQL's `BETWEEN` operator:

```
WHERE 
    `Profiles`.`Departure1` BETWEEN CAST('2012-04-01' AS Date) AND CAST('2012-04-04' AS Date) OR 
    `Profiles`.`Departure2` BETWEEN CAST('2012-04-01' AS Date) AND CAST('2012-04-04' AS Date) OR 
    `Profiles`.`Departure3` BETWEEN CAST('2012-04-01' AS Date) AND CAST('2012-04-04' AS Date)
```

See the documentation:

- `BETWEEN` - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between
- `CAST`/`CONVERT` - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert

A note: if this is the type of thing you're going to be doing a lot of, consider storing your dates as UNIX timestamps, using the `BIGINT` field type rather than a `Date`. That way you don't have to use `CAST` so much to do `BETWEEN` comparisons. You can use `FROM_UNIXTIME` ([docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)) to format on the way out of the db instead of monkeying around with converting every time you compare. See:

- PHP's `strtotime` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php
- PHP's `date` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
- mySQL's `FROM_UNIXTIME` - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

Comment: You don't have to cast at all. Just do `date_field BETWEEN "2012-01-01" AND "2012-01-10"`. Also, there is no need to convert the DATE field to accomodate timestamps as date range scans are [faster on DATE fields than on INTs](http://www.dbtuna.com/article.php?id=36).  

One has to be careful with DATETIME fields though as, if you do BETWEEN on those, it will "exclude" the last date, because for `BETWEEN "2000-01-01" AND "2000-01-10"` it will be technically executing BETWEEN "2000-01-01 00:00:00" AND "2000-01-10 00:00:00". So make sure you define correct closing times of "23:59:59".

Comment: Thanks for the remarks! The article you link to regarding the benchmark does not appear to deal with `INT`, but rather `TIMESTAMP` vs `DATE`. From the manual's discussion of the mechanics of `TIMESTAMP`, I am not surprised it is slower than `DATE`, but I would question `INT` being slower. As far as not needing to `CAST`, I don't like implicit conversion, even if it is baked in. I'll always use explicit typecasting because I think it makes for more direct and expressive code -- you know what the developer expected because I coded exactly that way. IMO, the less ambiguity, the better.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to get this cleaner but I have kept it long hand to show the problem with the query above.

You need to make a link between the sets of departure dates, the one above is too broad.

WHERE (`Profiles`.`Departure1` >= '2012-04-01' AND `Profiles`.`Departure1` <= '2012-04-04')
OR
(`Profiles`.`Departure2` >= '2012-04-01' AND `Profiles`.`Departure2` <= '2012-04-04')
OR
(`Profiles`.`Departure3` >= '2012-04-01' AND `Profiles`.`Departure3` <= '2012-04-04')